# Does the choice in education provider make a difference at interview time?

Tags: career-path, university

I am at a point where I am looking into all my options in my education. I am currently at a private university and am wondering if the location of where I am studying has any possible future ramifications. I would love to continue as far as I can go (PhD); however, I would like to know if I am safe to choose the institution freely or if there is a ranking I should be aware of.

Thank you kindly

Comment: What field are you in and what sort of careers are you looking at?

Comment: I am in the Bachelour of creative arts degree, and im looking at using games development process to increase production and design processes in other fields after i have finished my degree, the skills i need such as 3d and game engine programming are only attainable in this degree in my country

Comment: If you’re headed to industry, as long as the institution offers a solid education and you excel in your development you’ll be in good shape when the time comes. Make a point of being involved in several internships during your stay.

Comment: Thank you for that i have a few opportunities to jump into some work related positions to learn from the industry, just wanted to make sure that the upcoming masters degree before i sign on that I was making the right choice in institute, after all its the rest of my life that i have to make sure that i can achieve the goals i have set. sometimes that can be hindered by something silly like location or a choice i could overlook and deem as silly. I find its best to ask. Thank you for taking the time to respond. it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See and consider other comments and answers you get. Mine was but one.

Comment: Will do Thank you :)